# Are protocol buffers usable with F#?

Tags: f#, protocol-buffers

Just curious - are protocol buffers usable with F#? Any caveats etc.?

Comment: Do you mean this: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/? I'd expect the "usual" problems with serialization-like API - you'll maybe have to write mutable classes (which is a bit ugly in F#) and it may not work with F# records... (but I have no experience with the library)

Comment: @Tomas speaking as the author of protobuf-net, I take the question to mean protobuf **in general** (the wider family of protocol buffers implementations)

Comment: Just found this btw, but looks abandoned: http://code.google.com/p/froto/

Comment: I wrote a Google protocol buffer implementation in ~200 lines of F# code.

Comment: @Jon a *full* implementation? that would be interesting to see... And even more interesting to profile.

Comment: @Marc: I think its a full implementation, yes. @Dmitri: I'd rather sell it. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an F# specific one [listed here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns), but there is an [OCaml](http://piqi.org/) one, or there is a .NET "general" one ([protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)).

In all honesty, I simply haven't gotten around to trying protobuf-net with F# objects, in part because I simply don't know enough F#, but if you can create POCOs they should work. They would need to have *some* kind of mutability (perhaps even just private mutability) to work with protobuf-net, though.

If you are happy to generate a C# DTO and just *consume* that from F#, then protobuf-net or [Jon's port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port) should work just fine.

Answer (score 9):

I'm just trying to answer this question myself.

[Marc Gravell's protobuf-net project](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) worked out-of-the-box with F# because it uses standard .NET idioms. You can use attributes to get serializing without having to write .proto files or do any two-stage compilation, or you can generate the necessary code from standard .proto files. Performance is good for .NET but a lot slower than alternatives like OCaml's built-in `Marshal` module. However, this library forces you to make every field in every message type mutable. This is really counter-productive because messages should be immutable. Also, the documentation leaves a lot to be desired but, then, this is free software.

I haven't managed to get [Jon Skeet's protobuf-csharp-port library](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) to work at all yet.

Ideally, you'd be able to serialize all of the built-in F# types (tuples, records, unions, lists, sets, maps, ...) to this wire format out-of-the-box but none of the existing open source solutions are capable of this. I'm also concerned by the complexity of these solutions: Jon Skeet's is 88,000 lines of C# code and comments (!).

As an aside, I am disappointed to see that Google protocol buffers do not specify standard formats for `DateTime` or `decimal` numbers.

I haven't looked at Proto# yet and cannot even find a download for Froto. There is also [ProtoParser](http://code.thinkbeforecoding.com/protoparser) but it just parses .proto files and cannot actually serialize anything.

Comment: by way of update I suppose, CLIMutable has made things easier with protobuf-net, but still doesn't appear to play (out-of-the-box) with F# inbuilt types e.g. list. Froto appears alive but requires two-stage.

Answer (score 4):

I'd expect both [my own port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) and [Marc Gravell's](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) to work just fine with F#, to the same extent that any other .NET library does. In other words, neither port is written in a way which is likely to produce idiomatic F# code, but they should work.

My port will generate C# code, so you'll need to build that as a separate project for your serialization model - but that should interoperate with F# without any problems. The generated types are immutable (with mutable builders) so that should help in an F# context.

Of course, you could always take the core parts of either project and come up with an idiomatic F# solution too - whether you port the whole project to F# or use the existing libraries with an F# code generator and helper functions, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on the differences between your and Marc's version? Just curious as to why you guys aren't working together on this...

Comment: @Dmitri: Marc's is more .NET-idiomatic, from scratch. It integrates very nicely with WCF etc. Mine is a port of the Java version, which is more appropriate for people working with other languages and wanting one consistent API.